# Listview not loading properly

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to save a link from webview. From my webview class, I am saving the page url as below.

```
public void AddUrl(String page_url){
    SaveUrlActivity urlactivity = new SaveUrlActivity();
    urlactivity.saveurl(page_url);
}
```

My SaveUrlActivity class is as below:

```
public class SaveUrlActivity extends Activity {

public String url;
public ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_savedurl);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    saveurl(url);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent in = new Intent(SaveUrlActivity.this, DisPlayWebPageActivity.class);

            in.putExtra("page_url", url);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

public void saveurl(String url1){
    url = url1;
    final List<RowItem> ri = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    RowItem item = new RowItem(url);
    ri.add(item);
    SavedUrlAdapter adapter = new SavedUrlAdapter(SaveUrlActivity.this, ri);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Whenever I run my program, I am getting the following error.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smarthelp, PID: 16284
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.smarthelp.SaveUrlActivity.saveurl(SaveUrlActivity.java:46)
        at com.example.smarthelp.DisPlayWebPageActivity.AddUrl(DisPlayWebPageActivity.java:76)
        at com.example.smarthelp.DisPlayWebPageActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DisPlayWebPageActivity.java:66)
```

Can anyone help me figure out where I am making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using reference to ListView `lv` before it has been initialized, and you can't do that without first starting the SaveUrlActivity, only after it's `setContentView(R.layout.activity_savedurl);` you can initialize the `lv`.

```
public void saveurl(String url1){
    url = url1;
    final List<RowItem> ri = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    RowItem item = new RowItem(url);
    ri.add(item);
    SavedUrlAdapter adapter = new SavedUrlAdapter(SaveUrlActivity.this, ri);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

It would be easier if you make a static var in your `SaveUrlActivity` class and assign a value to it before you start the Activity, and the make call to the `saveurl()` from inside of that class when you have all your views initialized.

Something like:

```
public void AddUrl(String page_url){
    SaveUrlActivity.page_url = page_url;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SaveUrlActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And in your SaveUrlActivity.java:

```
public class SaveUrlActivity extends Activity {

public String url;
public ListView lv;
static page_url;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_savedurl);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    saveurl();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent in = new Intent(SaveUrlActivity.this, DisPlayWebPageActivity.class);

            in.putExtra("page_url", url);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

public void saveurl(){
    url = page_url;
    final List<RowItem> ri = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    RowItem item = new RowItem(url);
    ri.add(item);
    SavedUrlAdapter adapter = new SavedUrlAdapter(SaveUrlActivity.this, ri);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

It's accurate if you're planning to start this activity, if you need to update data in already started one, you better use the `Handler`

Comment: Ya I understand. That must be the reason. But I am not clearly getting your solution. Can u elaborate a little more..

Comment: @Arnab, you can't use ListView or any other View from the activity that hasn't been started yet. When you say `SaveUrlActivity urlactivity = new SaveUrlActivity();` - you're not calling to onCreate() from this class, onCreate() would be called only if you start this class as Activity, otherwise you just initialize it as an arbitrary class, you don't need that. I edited my answer, check it out

Comment: Thanks Movsar, I will try this out

Comment: @Arnab when you wrote ` SaveUrlActivity urlactivity = new SaveUrlActivity();` what do you wanted to do? To start this Activity? Or just call one it's method 'to do the job'?

Comment: I wanted to call one of its method to pass the url string.

Comment: It is working perfectly now. Thanks for your help Movsar. :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to look at:

1. Make sure that the `activity_savedurl` layout file actually contains a view with the `list` ID. If it does not, then `lv` will be `null`.
2. You pass `url` to `saveurl()`, but you never assigned it a value.

Comment: The lv value will be null in either way. He isn't got the error from `saveurl(url);` he is getting it when he does ` urlactivity.saveurl(page_url);`, the Activity is never started and thus the Views never are initialized so they all are null.

Comment: The stack trace states: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`.

Comment: yes, it says that he tries to setAdapter to ListView that hasn't been initialized.